# .bat renaming files runs multiple times

Tags: batch-file

So the script works well, I usually run it in the folder with the files I modify (Mainly .mp3's) to trim the first X characters from the filename (Numbers spaces dashes ect) of multiple files.

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set X=5
set FOLDER_PATH=.
pushd %FOLDER_PATH%
for %%f in (*) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    set "filename=!filename:~%X%!"
    ren "%%f" "!filename!%%~xf"
)
popd
```

But running it on my SD Card (Formatted for Galaxy S4 w./ Android 4.3) that I have plugged in it works perfectly for 70% of the files.  But for some it runs twice, and for a very rare few it acts like it hasn't run at all.  I'm completely befuddled by it, is it just the SD Card?

Comment: Sorry about the android tag, it was recommended and looking back it was irrelevant.  My bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple FOR command with wildcards begins iterating files before it finishes reading the entire directory. It buffers a block of files and iterates them, then picks up where it left off. When you rename a file, the renamed file may sort later in the list, and be picked up in a later block of files. Hence the double renaming.

Any time you have a loop that modifies the directory listing you should use FOR /F with the DIR /B command instead of the simple FOR.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d-h-s') do ...
```

The `EOL=:` is just in case a file name begins with `;` (unlikely, but possible). Other valid options with the same result are `EOL=*` or `EOL=?` - All are characters that cannot begin a file name or path.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is appreciated.  It'll help a lot in other areas too!